# Where does the CUDA_CLIIP http header come from?

Tags: nginx, php

I am running nginx with php-fpm and frequently in the error logs I see this:

2011/11/28 17:49:15 [info] 6709#0: *9230132 client sent invalid header line: "CUDA_CLIIP: x.x.x.x" while reading client request headers, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.mydomain.com, request: ...

These appear regularly in the nginx error log and obscure the information I am looking for. I cannot find any information on what CUDA_CLIIP is or what the source of it could be let alone how to fix or suppress it. Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Just wanted to link these two questions together. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590406/cuda-clip-http-header

Answer (score 1):

CUDA_CLIIP is some form of proprietary HTTP header that is used on web filtering devices manufactured by Barracuda. At least, to the best of my knowledge. I haven't seen these anywhere but on Barracudas.