# CUDA_CLIP Http Header?

Tags: nginx

While watching some log files the other day i saw a client suddenly start generating these error messages and for the life of me i cant figure out whats causing them.

```
2012/03/06 13:16:56 [info] 14212#0: *2018230 client sent invalid header line: 
"CUDA_CLIIP: 10.3.68.20" while reading client request headers, client: 72.162.16.3,  
server: <oursever.com>,    request: "GET /images/101431.jpg HTTP/1.0", host: "<ourhost>", 
referrer: "http://<ourserver.com>/<valid_url>"
```

This went on for more than 30 minutes before i dropped that ip in iptables. Fyi this is an nginx install.

The only information i could find online was this page: 
http://nemesis.te-home.net/Projects/AdvOR-Help/

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to turn [underscores_in_headers](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#underscores_in_headers) on;

Comment: I had the same issue too, the whole CUDA_CLIP header i mean. Any idea on where that comes from?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Searching for "CUDA_CLIIP" doesn't return anything helpful to figure out what client is sending that header.

Comment: It's (optionally) added by Barracuda web filters.